# Trouble with MP3 files served by Apache

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm having some problems with Apache serving a select few MP3 files. Most of the time our MP3 files are served and play properly. Sometimes they aren't, but using "lame -b 192 -h " fixes the problem. And sometimes it doesn't, for example this file:

http://web1.cowbird.com/items/stories/2012/03/22/10/56/15271/9b5ce75faa96ae2347a7d621ee2a1a2402e1257c9a488f6bd31df0c6d502533d-original.mp3

Lame fails while trying to re-code this file. However I can download it (via wget or curl) and play it locally with no problem. Any ideas? Here's the lame output:

```
ID3v2 found. Be aware that the ID3 tag is currently lost when transcoding.
LAME 3.98.2 64bits (http://www.mp3dev.org/)
Using polyphase lowpass filter, transition band: 16452 Hz - 17032 Hz
Encoding /src/cowbird-prod/content/items/stories/2012/03/22/10/56/15271/9b5ce75faa96ae2347a7d621ee2a1a2402e1257c9a488f6bd31df0c6d502533d-original.mp3
      to test.mp3
Encoding as 48 kHz j-stereo MPEG-1 Layer III (12x) 128 kbps qval=2
    Frame          |  CPU time/estim | REAL time/estim | play/CPU |    ETA 
     0/       ( 0%)|    0:00/     :  |    0:00/     :  |         x|     :  
     0/4205   ( 0%)|    0:00/    0:00|    0:00/    0:00|   0.0000x|    0:00 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     0/4205   ( 0%)|    0:00/    0:00|    0:00/    0:00|   0.0000x|    0:00 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     0/4205   ( 0%)|    0:00/    0:00|    0:00/    0:00|   0.0000x|    0:00 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
01:40-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   kbps      %     %
    0.0           bitstream problem: resyncing...
bitstream problem: resyncing...
bitstream problem: resyncing...
bitstream problem: resyncing...
     5/4205   ( 0%)|    0:00/    0:16|    0:00/    0:13|   6.0000x|    0:13 
-01:40------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   kbps        LR    MS  %     long switch short %
  128.0       80.0  20.0        40.0  40.0  20.0
Writing LAME Tag...done
ReplayGain: -14.3dB
```

Comment: Sorry to ask, but are you sure the original files are good ? If yes, does it always happen with the same files or is it random ?

Comment: They're good in so much as I can download and play them locally. Doesn't mean there's not a problem with the file of course - these are uploaded by the users of the site. It always happens with the same files, it's consistently reproducable.

Comment: Then we can exclue any network glitch corrupting transferred data.